# memory allocated in native code between jni calls

Tags: java, jvm, malloc

Can I allocate a memory block in one JNI function, and release one in another JNI function?

I'm afraid, that jvm catchs call of malloc from native function, and release it when function finished; For example, is this code correct:

```
char * buffer; 
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_test_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   buffer = malloc(1000);
   return (jlong)buffer; //for check it
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_use(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   // some code, that used buffer
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_done(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
   free(buffer);
}
```

UPD: I read about direct buffer (NewDirectByteBuffer) and global refererences (NewGlobalRef) but i asked, can I allocate memory without use JNI API, just with call 'malloc'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid approach.

JVM has no control on what native code does; it would possibly break many third-party libraries if it tried to intercept malloc/free calls. Futhermore, the similar approach is used by JDK code itself. Examples: [1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/53fe2fe14a86/src/share/native/com/sun/media/sound/DirectAudioDevice.c#l505), [2](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/53fe2fe14a86/src/share/native/com/sun/tools/jdi/SharedMemoryConnection.c#l205), [3](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/53fe2fe14a86/src/share/native/java/util/zip/ZipFile.c#l185).

Comment: Hey but its no longer thread safe, right ? if multiple thread is trying to access it , it might break

Comment: @alphaguy I'm not sure what you mean. Memory itself isn't "thread-safe" or "unsafe". It can be accessed in either thread-safe way or not in a thread-safe way.

Comment: I meant when you native init() method using multiple thread from java, this might break right ? 
As both thread may point to same memory location through bufffer, there is any other way so that we can free the buffer before returning the string back to java ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a global reference for your object, then it stays valid after returning from your JNI function. Which means that your example is correct.
For further information look here: [local and global references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242)

Comment: No, this means, that my example is INcorrect, because I not create global reference. In fact, I asked because read about local and global references

Comment: @AdelChepkunov Did you find any other way of doing this ? 
Can we make this a thread-safe ? if multiple thread is calling the init() ? 
cant we free the memory itself in jni before returning the string? so that when another thread calls this piece of code asynchronously, it doesnt faces any issues

Comment: @alphaguy Yes, my snippets is not thread-safe. If it is need to worked with different objects, it is possible to use some map with jobject-pointer as key, and pointer to allocated memory as value. I think that best way to make one thread-safe is use synchronization on java-side. PS. Sorry for long time to answer.